# Get request works in postman many times but blocked in pyrometer/curl/nodejs after several times

Tags: walmart-api

I have a url https://search.mobile.walmart.com/v1/products-by-code/UPC/889842615319?storeId=1 ,It return a Json through browser or get request.
When I use browser or postman to visit the url, it works well. But when I use curl/python to get the url, it works in first several times, then will be banned, but at the same time it still works in browser or postman. I just don’t why.  I add user agent to the curl/python. How did postman can works all the time and why python curl banned after several times.